# Using parentheses with possessive pronoun

Tags: adjectives, parentheses

The following statements makes sense

> It is impossible to doubt that you exist.
>
> It is impossible to doubt that your mind exists.

However, if I were to add parentheses to the first statement which contain the information in the second, it becomes unclear as to which form of `exist` I should use.

> It is impossible to doubt that you (or your mind) **exist**/**exists**.

Similarly and more confusingly:

> You (or he) **jump**/**jumps**.

Comment: We use parenthesis because it is not absolutely required in a sentence. The verb should agree with the subject outside it.

Comment: @Rathony I'd up-vote that in an answer. [Here's](http://www.grammaruntied.com/blog/?p=225) a sample link you can use for reference.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks for your comment. I don't think this question belongs on ELU even though I didn't close-vote it.

Comment: I agree with Rathony.  The verb should agree either with the subject outside the parenthesis, or (if you omit the brackets but leave the words within them) with the subject nearer the verb.  My other comment would be simply that one should avoid writing a sentence in such a way that this issue arises, e.g. "It is impossible to doubt either that you exist or that your mind exists."  This is a 'non-problem' - construct the sentence better!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Singular or plural verb after parenthetical material containing a conjunction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403708/singular-or-plural-verb-after-parenthetical-material-containing-a-conjunction)